# how to use ffmpeg with gpu support on macos

Tags: video, ffmpeg, gpu, render

When I exec ffmpeg command, it use my CPU to render videos, it take long time to do this job, how i can force ffmpeg use my GPU to render?

I have a macOS with AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB Graphic card. What I must install and what command i must use for this work?

I use this commands when my script run:

```
$source_decoder = "ffmpeg -i $film_aval_source -vf drawtext=\"text_shaping=1:fontfile=$font_source:
    text='$esme_film': fontcolor=black: fontsize=$font_size: box=1: boxcolor=black@0:
    boxborderw=0: x=(w-text_w)/2: y=(h-text_h)/2 :enable='between(t,5,10)'\"  -c:a copy -force_key_frames 0:05:00,0:6:00 $film_aval_dest";

$source_decoder = "ffmpeg -i $film_aval_source -i ".$path."/Data.jpg -filter_complex '[0:v][1:v]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2:enable=between(t\,5\,10)' -codec:a copy $film_aval_dest";

$convert1 = "ffmpeg -i $film_aval_dest -map 0 -flags:v +global_header -c:v libx264 -bsf:v dump_extra ".$path."output1.ts";

$convert_logo = "ffmpeg -i $path_tmp -i ".$main_path."/data/logo.png -filter_complex 'overlay=4:4' -codec:a copy $path_tmp2";

$convert2 = "ffmpeg -i $path_tmp2 -map 0 -flags:v +global_header -c:v libx264 -bsf:v dump_extra ".$path."output2.ts";
$merge = "ffmpeg -i 'concat:".$path."output1.ts|".$path."output2.ts' -map 0 -flags:v +global_header -c:v libx264 -bsf:v dump_extra ".$path."output_new.ts";
$convert3 = "ffmpeg -i  ".$path."output_new.ts -acodec aac -vcodec copy ".$path."video_out2.mp4";
```

thanks

Comment: @llogan your comment works for me. You should turn it into an answer.

Comment: @AnthonyKong I added an answer. I only made a comment previously because I don't have the hardware to test and confirm.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For hardware accelerated video encoding on macOS use:

| Format | Encoder |
| --- | --- |
| H.264 | `-c:v h264_videotoolbox` |
| HEVC/H.265 | `-c:v hevc_videotoolbox` |

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v h264_videotoolbox output.mp4
```

- For options specific to these encoders see `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_videotoolbox` and `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_videotoolbox`.
- These encoders do not support `-crf` so you must use `-b:v` to set the bitrate, such as `-b:v 6000k`.

Comment: encode quality was very poor using h264_videotoolbox - am I missing something... ?

Comment: @paj Increase the bitrate, such as `-b:v 4000k`. If you show the complete output of `ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_videotoolbox` I may be able to make another suggestion. You can use a pastebin site and provide a link in a comment. It is a simple encoder compared to x264, so it can't achieve the same quality at the same bitrate.

Comment: that helped thanks I forgot to specify a bit rate. Encoding time for a 10 min 1080p vid was a few seconds instead of 10 minutes with no noticeable difference in quality.

Comment: What about for HVEC (x265)?

Comment: Great! No more loud and crazy fan spinning! And the speed is increased from 27x to 41x.

Comment: @llogan, Is there something similar for vp9 webm encoding?

Comment: @llogan Can you accelerate splitting a two channel stereoscopic VR movie into two files using GPU? I run this command `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]crop=iw/2:ih:0:0[left];[0]crop=iw/2:ih:ow:0[right]" -map "[left]" -map 0:a left.mp4 -map "[right]" -map 0:a right.mp4` and the source file is H264. I tried adding `-c:v h264_videotoolbox ` to the command but it still run on the CPU. Using an IntelMac with Radeon.

Comment: @llogan Tried another operation, but got this error message: `[h264_videotoolbox @ 0x7f815400c000] Error: cannot create compression session: -12903
[h264_videotoolbox @ 0x7f815400c000] Try -allow_sw 1. The hardware encoder may be busy, or not supported.
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
[aac @ 0x7f8157808e00] Qavg: 65536.000
[aac @ 0x7f8157808e00] 2 frames left in the queue on closing` Does ffmpeg not support my Radeon 5500M 4 GB?